# How to search for a phone number stored inside of a mysql table between date 1 and date 2 using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure it out and and I'm stuck at a stand still.

I am creating a portal in which phone numbers are stored inside of a table called: `fusionnationweb_callrecordings` .

The table stores an ai, recording date, recording id, caller, receiver, time, and duration.
I am trying to create a searchable PHP form in which you enter a phone number in (which is stored in caller and receiver) and you enter a start date and end date.

The form will then display a table that shows all entry's for the specified phone number between the start and end date.

This is what I have so far; please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="search.php?go" method="post">  
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:none;}
                        .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
                        .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
                        .tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
                        .tg .tg-fefd{color:#000000;vertical-align:top}
                    </style>
    <div align="center">
        <table class="tg">
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-yw4l">Phone Number:<br></th>
                <th class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="phonenumber" /><br /><br></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-yw4l">Start Date:<br></td>
                <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="startdate" /><br /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-yw4l">        End Date: <br></td>
                <td class="tg-fefd"><input type="text" name="enddate" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
        <table class="tg"></br>
            <tr><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</form>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Above is the main code
Below is the search.php

```
<?php
$db_hostname = 'removed';
$db_username = 'removed';
$db_password = 'removed';
$db_database = 'removed';

// Database Connection String
$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect - please consult your database administrator: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM fusionnationweb_callrecordings WHERE `recordingdate` BETWEEN '%".$startdate."%' AND '%".$enddate."%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
                $tableid=$row['Table ID'];  
                $recordingdate=$row['Recording Date'];  
                $recordingid=$row['Recording ID'];  
                $caller=$row['Caller'];  
                $receiver=$row['Receiver'];
                $time=$row['Time of Call'];  
                $callduration=$row['Call Duration']; 
        }  

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error?

Comment: Not getting a damn thing. Would you like to test it ? The screen is just blank

Comment: I can't test your code as I am not near my system but when u run your code do you see any errors or any kind of exceptions

Comment: The code is on a live website. And no, after form submission it brings me to search.php and the entire screen is blank.

Comment: On your search.php can you print out the parameters you getting from first page for eg start date, end date

Comment: Remove ' near the recordingdate in your sql

Comment: I see no `go` GET array nor anything else related to the inputs.

Comment: Honestly, I'm very new to the php and mysql scene, I'm unsure as how to do this, I'll google it, see if I can find something and post when I do it.

Comment: Try this tutorial then http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlphptutorial/

Comment: What is data type for the `recordingdate` field?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is the format . It's the basis for default date in mysql